# Postcode verify only 4 digits not working

Tags: javascript

this is my java for verifing a postcode it is working for the blank field but i cant get it to verify that it only contains the 4 digits

```
//  Check postcode
  const postcode = document.getElementById('postcode');
  const postcodeValue = postcode.value.trim();
  const postcoder = /^[0-9]\d{4}$/;
  if(postcodeValue === () {
    setErrorFor(postcode, 'Postcode cannot be blank');
  } else if(!postcoder.test(postcodeValue)) {
    setErrorFor(postcode, 'Postcode must contain 4 digits');
  } else {
    setSuccessFor(postcode);
  }
```

I want it to show an error message if there is more or less than 4 digits or if there is anything other than numbers.

Comment: Java or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression, `^[0-9]\d{4}$` matches

- `^`: start-of-text, followed by
- `[0-9]`: a US-ASCII decimal digit (0-9), followed by
- `\d{4}`: exactly 4 US-ASCII decimal digits (0-9), followed by
- `$`: end-of-text

So it matches 5 digits.